# Indexing items in a Wt List Model

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, model, wt

Why when using Wt list models must you specify a column in the `data` and `index` methods?

[The WAbstractListModel doc](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/classWt_1_1WAbstractListModel.html#details) says, "An abstract list model specializes WAbstractItemModel for one-dimensional lists (i.e. a model with 1 column and no children)."

The `WAbstractListModel::index` prototype is `index (int row, int column, const WModelIndex &parent=WModelIndex())`.  Wouldn't it make sense to also have `index (int row, const WModelIndex &parent=WModelIndex())`?

The same situation is found in `WStringListModel::data`, whose prototype is `data (int row, int column, int role=DisplayRole, const WModelIndex &parent=WModelIndex())`?  Wouldn't it make sense for WStringListModel (or any implementation of WAbstractListModel) to provide a method `data (int row, int role=DisplayRole, const WModelIndex &parent=WModelIndex())`?

I realize that Wt is incomplete in many ways.  Is the lack of a one-dimensional API for list models simply a result of that incompleteness?  Or is there some conceptual reason to require specification of column numbers here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Response from Wt developer](http://redmine.emweb.be/boards/1/topics/12103?r=12107):

> WAbstractListModel doesn't add much (besides expressing intent).
>
> The item models and views have been modelled after those in Qt, and
>   are in most ways the same as those provided by Qt. See for example
>   http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html

That Qt link shows that both of my suggestions are implemented there.

[QAbstractListModel::index](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html#index) does not require you to specify a column:

`QModelIndex QAbstractListModel::index(int row, int column = 0, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const`

And, [QStringListModel::data](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html#data) does not have a column parameter:

`QVariant QStringListModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const`

So, I'm chalking this up to "incompleteness."